# Creating new PHP project in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: php, xampp, aptana, htdocs

I am using Aptana Studio 3 as my PHP framework. While creating a new PHP project in Aptana, I have recently seen a video tutorial wherein it is being shown that the "*Use Default Location*" button has been deselected. In my case, on doing so, it is showing that the specified folder in the xampp htdocs is not empty.

Comment: Help you to do what exactly?

Comment: Aptana Studio is an IDE not a PHP-Framework..

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that @Stony.

Comment: I actually want to know how to set my location of the PHP Project on htdocs of xampp folder. The moment I am setting the location out of the default location, I am facing problems stating this "overlaps location of another project". What to do? @ Mark Graph